# Angular 7 - Change base URL of a single component inside Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

All of my routes go to the plural version `builder-jobs/` but I would like to know if I can change one to go to `builder-job/:id` but leave the rest as `builder-jobs`

This is my current module file - `builder-jobs.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BuilderJobModule } from '@/modules/builder-jobs/builder-job.module';
import {
    QualityInspectionAddComponent,
    QualityInspectionViewComponent,
    SafetyInspectionAddComponent,
    SafetyInspectionViewComponent,
} from '@/modules/jobs/job.module';

import { AuthGuard } from '@/guards/auth/auth.guard';
import { Role } from '@/models/role';

import { BuilderJobsCalendarComponent } from './builder-jobs-calendar/builder-jobs-calendar.component';
import { BuilderJobsViewComponent } from './builder-jobs-view/builder-jobs-view.component';
import { BuilderJobsAddComponent } from './builder-jobs-add/builder-jobs-add.component';
import { BuilderJobComponent } from './builder-job/builder-job.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'view',
        component: BuilderJobsViewComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'add',
        component: BuilderJobsAddComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {
        path: 'calendar',
        component: BuilderJobsCalendarComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor] }
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: BuilderJobComponent,
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: ':id/safety-inspection/:checklist_id',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: SafetyInspectionViewComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id/safety-inspection-add',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: SafetyInspectionAddComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id/quality-inspection/:checklist_id',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: QualityInspectionViewComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':id/quality-inspection-add',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: QualityInspectionAddComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/builder-jobs/view',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/builder-jobs/view',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BuilderJobsCalendarComponent,
        BuilderJobsViewComponent,
        BuilderJobsAddComponent,
        BuilderJobComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BuilderJobModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
})
export class BuilderJobsModule { }
```

I want to change the specific route of:

```
{
    path: ':id',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: BuilderJobComponent,
    data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
},
```

I tried `path: 'builder-job/:id'` but that doesn't seem to work - Goes to a 404

here is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from '@/guards/auth/auth.guard';

import { DashboardComponent } from '@/views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '@/views/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '@/views/login/login.component';
import { PasswordResetComponent } from '@/views/password-reset/password-reset.component';
import { NewPasswordComponent } from '@/views/new-password/new-password.component';

import { Role } from '@/models/role';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'incidents',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/incidents/incidents.module').then(mod => mod.IncidentsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.DashboardModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'builders',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/builders/builders.module').then(mod => mod.BuildersModule),
    },
    {
        path: 'communities',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/communities/communities.module').then(mod => mod.CommunitiesModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'reroof-jobs',
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/reroof-jobs/reroof-jobs.module').then(mod => mod.ReroofJobsModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {
        path: 'builder-jobs',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/builder-jobs/builder-jobs.module').then(mod => mod.BuilderJobsModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'repair-jobs',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/repair-jobs/repair-jobs.module').then(mod => mod.RepairJobsModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'warranty-jobs',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/warranty-jobs/warranty-jobs.module').then(mod => mod.WarrantyJobsModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'employees',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/employees/employees.module').then(mod => mod.EmployeesModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor] }
    },
    {
        path: 'contacts',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/contacts/contacts.module').then(mod => mod.ContactsModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor] }
    },
    {
        path: 'users',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/users/users.module').then(mod => mod.UsersModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor] }
    },
    {
        path: 'time-entries',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/time/time.module').then(mod => mod.TimeModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'alerts',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: () => import('@/views/alerts/alerts.module').then(mod => mod.AlertsModule),
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Supervisor, Role.CrewLeader] }
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'password-reset',
        component: PasswordResetComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'new-password',
        component: NewPasswordComponent
        },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot( routes )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't seem to work, you are getting any error? and what statement you are using to navigate, plus where do you have your router outlets.

Comment: @AakashGarg - it goes to a 404 not found. and sorry, but i suck with angular and don't know it very well. Do you mean the routerLinks? i have ```routerlink="builder-job/{{ id }}"```. The only ```<router-outlet>``` I see is in ```app.component.html```

Comment: and where is your root route config? you have only given child route config.

Comment: @AakashGarg - I have added my routes from ```app-routing.module.ts``` 

I can see that the parent path is ```'builder-jobs'```, so that's where it is coming from, but i wonder if I can change specific routes within that. It doesn't look like it based on this current configuration

Comment: you need to have this path in your app-routing.module.ts to have it like builder-job/:id because in current module you can only have it like builder-jobs/builder-job/:id

Comment: @AakashGarg - That makes sense, but since all the routes are in a single module, I'm not sure how i would create multiple paths that load the same module inside ```app-routing.module.ts``` and then specify that inside the ```builder-jobs.module.ts```. Maybe there is a way but I'm not sure how. I only have a single Routes array

Comment: i am saying make that id component part of appmodule instead of builder-jobs module.